# SQL Server 2008 R2 - find differences between select statements

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, not-exists, notin

How would I find the differences between two select statements based on the same table?  For example:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table as TableA
WHERE Date = '2016-04-30'
```

Based on the above select statement, I  want to find all the IDs that don't exist in:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table as TableB
WHERE Date = '2016-03-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier answer is a smart one. This is one simple way to do it.

```
Select ID from Table
where Date = '2016-04-30' 
and ID not in (select ID from Table where Date = '2016-03-31')
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Table
group by ID
having sum(case when Date = '2016-04-30' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when Date = '2016-03-31' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```